# Restrict access to certain websites without VPN

Tags: network, vpn, firewall

So I'd like to disable some connections to certain IPs and websites without a VPN activated for security purposes so I wouldn't mess up and go to that certain website without a VPN enabled, I wonder if there's a firewall rule approach or any other suggestions that I can limit access based on my current IP or the active VPN profile

Generally, I also use Wireguard if that's any help, also am using Catalina

Comment: Wireguard is just a VPN. You would need some kind of *outbound* firewall that you can passwordprotect. Little Snitch would do this but I don't see how you can restrict access to that program as it doesn't have an option to require a password to change rules.

Comment: Yes I just mentioned Wireguard as the preferred method of my VPN usage, the firewall must restrict a certain IP range (my own IP) or checks whether an app is controlling the network (Wireguard)